# W3wp.exe process may crash intermittently when an application handles requests for extensionless URLs in IIS 7.0 or in IIS 7.5

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, .net-4.0, .net-3.5

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2522807

I just wanted to know if anyone else has run this patch and have found any issue with it reducing the amount of IIS connection it is accepting.  Now it could be our LB that is causing this and we are checking on that but the funny thing is that for a very short period of time it ramps up the connection pool as it normally does and then drops off.  Based on this I would be surprised if it was the LB but I am not ruling anything out at this point.

Windows2K8 R2 SP1
IIS 7.5

Please let me know if anyone else has seen something like this once this patch is installed

Answer (score 0):

We found out what the issue was and it had nothing to do with this patch, it was a problem with a PS script we using and setting keep-alives.

And now we have that sorted here is a link to a song I am listen to :)

http://grooveshark.com/s/20th+Century+Towers/2r7cd7?src=5